# Как получить массив данных через Ajax в Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

Суть такая: В js у меня генерируется массив данных, после чего отображаются на странице. По кнопке они должны отправляться на сервер и в бд. Не пойму, как через Ajax корректно это реализовать. До добавление в бд еще не дошел, остановился на том, как в принципе вытащить данные на сервер, при отработке функции получаю 200, но ничего не происходит

```
 function Upload_Card(){

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:  card_array,
        url:  "%5Eupload_card$",        
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.operation_status == 'ok') {
                alert ('All done ok')
            } else {
                alert ('Ups. Found some error!')
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("GG")
        }

    });
}





def upload_card(request):
    array_card = request.POST.get("card_array[]")
    return HttpResponse(array_card)



urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='MainPage'),
    path(r'^upload_card$', views.upload_card, name='upload_card'),

]
```

Comment: data:{card_array:card_array}

Comment: `upload_card` => тут укажите `request.POST.getlist('card_array')` или `request.POST.getlist('card_array[]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для получения списка, тебе необходимо использовать метод getlist.
поправь сперва ajax:

```
url:  "{% url 'upload_card' %}",
```

Твой пример:

```
array_card = request.POST.get("card_array[]")
```

изменить на

```
array_card = request.POST.getlist("card_array")
```

print(array_card) для того чтобы просмотреть что получилось по итогу, а дальше уже запись в бд